# Build Windows app compatible for 8.1 and 10

Tags: webview, uwp, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal

**Background:**
I am new to Windows app development.
I have installed Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition free trial on two machines. (One is running win 8.1 OS and other having win 10 OS)
Then, downloaded windows 10 sdk and mobile emulators.
I have created a webview based UWP app which is targeting windows 10.

**Problem:**
Built UWP app is running perfectly on Windows 10 OS with mobile emulators target version windows 10.
Now, I want the app to run on both windows 8, 8.1 and windows 10 phones.
I have installed windows 10 and windows 8.1 sdk on both machines.
But, it is not allowing me to create a new project to specify minimum sdk version as 8 or 8.1. 
[image: Please find attached image herewith]
[image: Please find attached image herewith]

Is there any way to target both 8.1 and 10 versions for mobile with single app, with minimum efforts?

Please suggest.

Comment: you can create two separate package for win10 and win 8 separately because uwp version support tablet and pc also and with new controls but if you want windows 8 support you have two options create different package for both or create single windows 8 package which support win 8 and win 10 as well but you cant create windows 8 apps in vs2017 you maximum can use vs2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a summary that which VS can build which app models:

- VS2019 - UWP (Except for Win10Mobile)
- VS2017 - UWP
- VS2015 - UWP, Win8.1 StoreApp, WP8/8.1 StoreApp
- VS2013 - Win8/8.1 StoreApp, WP8/8.1 StoreAp

(Assume that dev system is Win10 and ignoring the Win32 or others)

(Note - To use the latest Win10 FallCU SDK, you need to use VS2017 or 2019)

For detail, please refer the vs compatibility page:

- [VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/compatibility)
- [VS2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs)
- [VS2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2015-compatibility-vs)
- [VS2013](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2013-compatibility-vs)

Comment: Oh! Thanks @pnp0a03. Where should I download VS2015? on Windows8.1 OS machine or Windows10 OS?

Comment: Win10 is ok. Perhaps you may need the Win8.1 test machine, but this is another story I think.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an app using Windows 8 SDK if you want to target Windows 8 and above versions.

UWP will not work for you because minimum requirement for UWP is Windows 10.

Comment: Do I need to create two separate apps?

Comment: If you are creating using Windows 8.1 SDK then one single app can be installed on Windows 8.1 phone and Windows 10 phone.

Comment: The issue is, although I have installed windows8.1 sdk, visual studio 2017 on my windows8.1 OS not allowing me to create app using windows8.1 sdk. Please see the images I have added in question.

Comment: Yes you will not be able to create Windows 8.1 app on VS 2017, you need to have VS 2015 or VS 2013

Comment: Thanks Ipsit gaur